# How to change Share text on Invite Family and Friends

Tags: android-studio, mesibo

I am looking to re-brand the Mesibo app https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android/

Mesibo docs says we can change everything. However I am unable to find a way to change small things where it says "Mesibo".
For example on the Invite Family and Friends screen, it shows Mesibo name its links to download Mesibo app. Which of course we need to change to ours.

How can we do that?

Project is compiled and runs all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you already find by yourself. But if not, this information and more comes from backend API server code. Check out API server code: https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-backend/blob/master/api_functions.php and change response text, or you can overwrite Mesibo server answer in application.

```
    $invite['text'] = 'Hey, I use Mesibo for free messaging, voice and video calls. Download it from https://m.mesibo.com';
```